# Select radio button with dynamic Id, using CSS selector or Xpath

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I'm using C# in Visual Studio to select multiple yes or no questions. Below is the first button to select "yes". The `id` is not static so can't use that, and I'm not sure which path (CSS or Xpath) is the most efficient for this route.

```
<div class="row form-group">
  <label class="form-label col-md-4 col-lg-3">Was everything satisfactory?</label>
  <div class="col-md-7 col-lg-8"><fieldset class="form-group form-radio-group" id="__BVID__385">
    <div tabindex="-1" role="group"><div role="radiogroup" tabindex="-1" class="" id="__BVID__386">
      <div class="custom-control custom-control-inline custom-radio">
        <input type="radio" autocomplete="off" class="custom-control-input" value="true" id="__BVID__387" name="__BVID__386">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="__BVID__387">Yes</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I usually prefer XPath for its precision. Something like `//label[.="Yes"]/preceding::input[1]` in order to click() should work.  Additional reading : http://elementalselenium.com/tips/32-xpath-vs-css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its best to use Xpath when you have dynamic CSS Ids, name.

Based on your requirement ('select multiple yes or no questions') you should have a relation b/w Questions and option.

you can make a Xpath relationship between two elements like in below samples.

```
//label[contains(.,'Was everything satisfactory?')]/following-sibling::div/fieldset/div/div/div/label[.='Yes' or .='No']
```

Or

```
//label[.='Yes' or .='No']/ancestor::div/parent::body/label[contains(.,'Was everything satisfactory')]
```

Update these Xpaths as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

If you are better of using XPath or CSS selector comes down to the element at hand and personal preferences. The [article](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/32-xpath-vs-css) linked by [E. Wiest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9978746/e-wiest) has some good points.

In  your concrete case, you can either use a CSS selector like [`:checked`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/)

```
input[type='radio']:checked
```

- if you want to select the subsequent `label` for instance

  ```
  input[type='radio']:checked+label
  ```

Or some XPath as suggested

```
//label[contains(text(), "Yes")]/preceding::input
```

Personally, I also consider XPath to be more powerful but a CSS selector is usually equally adequate.